# UDP request in Jmeter

Tags: udp, jmeter

I have a wireshark trace and need to create a UDP request in Jmeter.I'm using the UDP request sampler in Jmeter and need to understand on what basis do we have to select the DataEncode/Decode class and the Request data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UDP Request plugin documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UDPRequest/):

- **[Encode/Decode Class](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UDPRequest/#Encode-Decode-Class)** - in case if UDP request returns binary (non-text) data you **may** want to convert it into human-readable form for verification or later reuse i.e. for [Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) or [Correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) purposes. If you don't know what to put there - just use `kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.UDPSampler`value, it will return data "as is"
- **Request Data**- here you can paste request payload from the Wireshark trace, this is what will actually be sent to the specified endpoint

Comment: In the UDP sampler, we have something called as Hostname/IP. What do we need to pass there - the source IP or the destination IP? If we can pass only the source Up, then where to pass the other one and vice versa?